# How to persist application data?

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.7

I am new to Qt, so i dont know how to save application data in it, is there any way to do it like shared preferences in android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For saving application settings use [QSettings](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html).